# Getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException" when trying to connect vis https to third party site using JBoss

Tags: https, jboss, jboss7.x, truststore

I’m using Java 6 and JBoss 7.1.3.  I want to make https connections in my web application to a third-party web site.  Normally, when I try, I get the exception

```
10:35:45,597 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport] (http-/0.0.0.0:8443-1) Error getting client certs: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352) [jsse.jar:1.6]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getX509Certificates(JSSESupport.java:88)     [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSESupport.getPeerCertificateChain(JSSESupport.java:142) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.action(Http11Processor.java:1059) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.Request.action(Request.java:362) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAttribute(Request.java:1125) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getAttributeNames(Request.java:1179) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getAttributeNames(RequestFacade.java:286) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.application.WebappLifecycleListener.requestDestroyed(WebappLifecycleListener.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.11-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.requestDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:369) [jsf-impl-2.1.11-jbossorg-3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:372) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:679) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:931) [jbossweb-7.0.17.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) [classes.jar:1.6.0_65]
```

So I figured I needed to add the CA to a truststore and tell JBoss about it.  I downloaded the 3rd party CA cert in PEM form and created a trust store using

```
keytool -import -file thirdparty.pem -alias thirdparty -keystore truststore.ts
```

using the password “changeit”.  Then, I set a JBoss system property like so:

```
    <property name="javax.net.ssl.trustStore" value="/opt/jboss-as-7.1.3.Final/standalone/configuration/truststore.ts" />
</system-properties>
```

However, after stopping and restarting my server, attempts to connect to that third party site result in the same exception.  What am I missing in my configuration? (PS, I’m happy to configure this in my WAR file itself as opposed to the entire JBoss environment).

Thanks, - Dave

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try
1. Import it using **-trustcacerts** option
2. Import it into the cacerts file that is in the jdk (under jre/lib/security)
Restart and retry